# mysql insertion where not exists syntax error. I have no idea what is wrong

Tags: mysql

```
 insert into creditcard_info (member_id,card_type,card_number) 
 values ('1','Discover','555') 
 where not exists (
       select * from creditcard_info 
       where card_number='555' and
             card_type='Discover')
```

I want to be able to check if a card number already exists.. 
If card_number exists and card card_type exists then don't add
else insert this new card number along with card type

I am having difficultly with inserting into a table where a certain number does not exists.

Im getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select * from 
creditcard_info where card_number='555')' at line 2
```

Thank you all in advance for helping me :)

Comment: Create unique index for `card_number + card_type` fields

Comment: the thing is that card type is only set to a few types and is not unique....also number can be same with different type.... i just want it so that it checks if there exists a card type and card number exists as a record

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to perform an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) statement.

However, adding a unique index in both fields should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a multi-column unique index. The code is as below:

```
ALTER TABLE creditcard_info ADD UNIQUE idx_card_number_card_type(card_number,card_type);
```

This should run as a separate query. And you need to add it once.

The other possible option is to add before insert trigger if the condition is more complicated than a simple unique check.
Here is the `create trigger` syntax:

```
Create Trigger card_type_unique_card_number_exists Before Insert on creditcard_info
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE it_exists INT;
        Set it_exists=(select count(*) from creditcard_info where card_number='555' and card_type='Discover');
        If it_exists>0 Then
            #Throw a meaningful exception by let's say inserting into a table which doesn't exist or something
        END IF;
    END
```

Comment: the thing is that card type is only set to a few types and is not unique....also number can be same with different type....

i just want it so that it checks if there exists a card type and card number exists as a record

Comment: The above unique index will make the combination unique. It is not gonna be applied to every single column in the list. You code have rows with similar card_type `XOR` card_number but the combination should be unique. If that's still not what you mean, You could go for before insert trigger. I am gonna add it to up there in a minute.